# Is og:image and copyright free when using on own site?

Tags: copyright

When using `og:image` the website tell other sites that Facebook and other social media platforms can use this image as a preview for a shared link.

If I have a site that is not a social media platform, like a blog or just a news collection site, can I use their image specified in `og:image`?

This question has been asked before on other forums but no one seems to have an answer for it.

**This one question can be split into a few subquestions:**

1. Can I use an image from a site from `og:image` on my site as a preview of a news snippet Without breaking a copyright rule?
2. How can Facebook download and use `og:image` without asking anyone about it? `og:` is not a Facebook specific tag.

*For more context around my question: I'm building a site that collects news from various sources and on the site group them by location. I know Google will not like it because of duplicate content but my trafic will come direct trafic from returning users.*

Comment: Seems a similar question has already answers here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125768/opengraph-image-and-license